# connect only dispatcher to component without connecting states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm writing a component (say `ComponentUpdate`) that modifies a list of items which is used by another component (say `ComponentDisplay`) that re-renders and display the new updated list.

So in that case, `ComponentUpdate` is using one of the dispatchers and have nothing to do with the store, it only dispatches a new list of items.

So to a dispatcher, I'm connecting the component with the dispatcher function I'm using `react-redux` `connect` method.

**Is there any way of doing this without passing mapStateToProps in the connect function?**

---

> I'm connecting like -

```
   const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return state;
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return ({
            dispatchfunction: filters => dispatch(dispatchfunction(filters)),
        })
    }

    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentUpdate)
```

> I want something like this, but it is not working out:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
            return ({
                dispatchfunction: filters => dispatch(dispatchfunction(filters)),
            })
        }

connect(mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentUpdate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `null` instead of `mapStateToProps`

`connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentUpdate`)

Or

You can `import store from './redux'` and call the action like, `store.dispatchFunction(filters)` anywhere you want. So you don't want to use `connect` function